# convert ""Serial #"" to "Serial #"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have tried below codes but not able to get result like "Serial #".
where column = ""Serial #"";

var b = column.replace(/\""/g, '"');

var b = column.replace(/" "/g, '"');

thanks

Comment: `b=column.replace(/\"\"/g, '"')`

Comment: think about it. You are replacing each " for another one. How should the result change? :)

Comment: Which is your actual value? This one `var column = "\"Serial #\""`? You can try `var b = column.substring(1, column.length-1)`.

Comment: Do you just want to replace quote in the string (") with an empty string? like, column.replace(/\"/g, "");

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the string is actually "Serial", than you either want to do

```
var column = "\"Serial #\"";  
var updated = column.replace(/^"|"$/g,""); //matches start of string followed by a quote or quote followed by end of the string
```

or

```
var column = "\"Serial #\"";
var updated = column.replace(/"/g,""); //matches any quote
```

Now if the string is actually ""Serial"" than you would need to double up on the quotes.

```
var column = '""Serial #""';
column.replace(/^"+|"+$/g,"")
```

or

```
var column = '""Serial #""';
var updated = column.replace(/"+/g,""); //matches any quote
```